# React Redux and state after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with understanding why my app works kinda odd. When I try to reach any site on my page by clicking a link button in navbar, it navigates me there without any problems, like when I click "My account", the URL changes to "http://localhost:3000/my_account" and everything works just fine. In this place I have to mention that "/my_account" is a protected route - user has to be logged in to reach it, when he is not logged in - he gets send to the homepage. So now the problem is that when user is logged in and tries to reach the protected route like "http://localhost:3000/my_account" by entering this URL and loading page - he is treated like a non-logged user and gets redirected to the homepage. And after he is redirected there and tries to reach this site by clicking the navbar link, he can enter this page - he is logged in. My expected result is that user can enter any URL on the site and react should check PROPRERLY if he is logged in in both cases - either when clicking a link on site or by providing a url. Can anyone tell me where do I make mistake?

UserAccount (/my_account) is a simple component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class UserAccount extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                UserAccount
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserAccount
```

In router in App.js I declare this route as:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/my_account" exact component={UserAccount}></PrivateRoute>
```

And the PrivateRoute is a functional component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


const PrivateRoute = ({component : Component, auth, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if(auth.isLoading){
            return <h2>LOADING ...</h2>
        }
        else if(!auth.isAuthenticated){
            return <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
        }
        else{
        return <Component {...props}/>
        }
    
    }}></Route>
)
    


const mapStateToProps = state =>({
auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(PrivateRoute);
```

My state in auth.js (reducer):

```
const initialState = {
    access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
    refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading : false,
    user: null,
    requestSent: false,
    payload: null,
    message: null
}
```

And after successful login, state changes as follows:

```
    switch(type){
        case AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true
            } 
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            return{
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                access: payload.access,
                refresh: payload.refresh
            }
```

And login function from auth.js actions:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch =>{
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    
    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

    try{
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        dispatch(load_user());
        dispatch(createMessage({logged_in_successfully: "You are now logged in."}))
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: err
        })
        const errors =  {msg: err.response.data, status: err.response.status}
        dispatch({
            type:GET_ERRORS,
            payload: errors
        })
    }
};
```

Thanks for your time reading that and I am hoping for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well probably I found a solution. Since I am setting a null value in a store as default, I've changed my PrivateRoute code to check if it is null, if it is, we wait with rendering or redirecting until it becomes true or false:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


const PrivateRoute = ({component : Component, auth, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if(auth.isLoading){
            return <h2>LOADING ...</h2>
        }
        else if(auth.isAuthenticated==null){
            return <h2>LOADING ...</h2>
        }
        else if(auth.isAuthenticated==false){
            return <h2>Not authenticated ... redirecting here</h2>
        }
        else{
        return <Component {...props}/>
        }
    
    }}></Route>
)

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
auth: state.auth,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(PrivateRoute);
```

Can anyone tell me if it is a good or bad idea?

Comment: if this solves your problem, set it as a solution, it would be helpful for future developers

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function UserAccount() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        let authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('access')
     
        // if user is not authed, redirect user to login page
        if (!authToken) {
            navigate('/login')
        }

     }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            Home Page
        </div>
    )
}
```

*Answer uses functional component and react router v6+. If you provide which version of react-router you're using I can update my answer*

You forgot to add condition for checking weather user is authed or no. For this, you need to check inside UserAccount Page. I provided snippet. Condition should be write inside `useEffect` in functional component. Inside class based component inside `componentDidMount`. More about authentication can be found
[here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth)

Besides that, you should also add condition inside `Login` page and `Register` page. To protect user from reregistering and re-logining again.

Comment: Hmmm, I just wonder if my PrivateRoute doesn't do the same thing? Doesn't it check if the user is logged in? Component UserAccount is passed to PrivateRoute as a prop, so I guess it should be checked with the functions that PrivateRoute has inside?

Comment: I tried to follow tutorial that has a very similar code to this example: 

https://medium.com/@eymaslive/securing-react-redux-application-public-private-routes-337f0ab19b3

Comment: And moreover, should we just check the fact that "access" is in localStorage without checking if it is valid? Can't everyone just manipulate their own localstorage?

Comment: Please look at my answer and correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I edited you answer, check it

Comment: Thank you for your help, it got me on the right track!